# Question on binomial expansion - divisibility by power of divisor

Tags: divisibility, binomial-theorem

By the Binomial theorem, one has that $$(a+b)^n = a^n + \binom{n}{1} \ a^{n-1}b + \binom{n}{2}\  a^{n-2}b^2 + \dots + b^n$$

Let us suppose that $d\mid (a+b)$, where $\mid$ means "divides", and such that $d>1$, $n>1$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$

Could it be proved that $d^n\nmid a^n+b^n$?

Comment: you obviously need some conditions like $d>1, n>1$; consider $2|4+6$ and $2^3|4^3+6^3$

Comment: You are right @J.W.Tanner, I proceed to edit the question

Comment: Even with the updated constraint, I believe that $a = 3$, $b = 5$, $d = 2$ and $n = 2$ is a counterexample. $2\mid3+5$ and $2^3\mid 3^3 + 5^3$.

Comment: Thanks @AryamanMaithani, you are right! But what if we set the constraint n>2? I believe this question could be connected with FLT, this is the main motivation behind it.

Comment: Argh, I can't edit my comment now but as you can see, I actually meant $n = {\color{red}3}$, not $2$, @JuanMoreno

Comment: Oh, thanks @AryamanMaithani! So question closed ;)

Comment: Great, now that the constraints aren't being changed, I shall add that as an answer for completeness' sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2 \mid 3 + 5; \quad 2^3 \mid 3^3 + 5^3.$$
Thus, $(a, b, d, n) = (3, 5, 2, 3)$ is a counterexample.